# Is Bernoulli's equation the correct explanation of a curved soccer ball?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, projectile, bernoulli-equation, lift

I saw a lot of materials supposing that the Bernoulli's equation explains the curvature of a soccer ball: since the ball is spinning, two sides of the ball would experience different velocities, and due to Bernoulli's theory, the side with slower velocity generates a higher pressure and push the ball to the other side.

However, when we first learnt the Bernoulli's equation, one of the fundamental criteria is that **it must be applied on the same streamline**. And in the above case, the streamlines on the two sides of the ball are separated. So how does the Bernoulli's theory explain the curving-ball phenomenon? Is that a misconception?

Comment: The Bernoulli is applicable for a streamlined flow, no turbulence.  But in this case, the flow becomes turbulent. The phenomenon is known as Magnus effect https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect  Bernoulli is not a correct explanation of this phenomenon.